# SIgn-in error in .NET 6 web application using Microsoft Identity (aka: Azure Active Directory)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, .net-6.0

I'm trying to use Microsoft Identity (formerly: Azure AD) authentication in an ASP.NET web application running on .NET 6

I've used this code to configure authentication in my startup class `ConfigureServices` method:

```
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options => {
            options.Instance = appSettings.UserSettings.AzIdInstance;
            options.Domain = appSettings.UserSettings.AzIdDomain;
            options.TenantId = appSettings.UserSettings.AzIdTenantId;
            options.ClientId = appSettings.UserSettings.AzIdClientId;
            options.CallbackPath = appSettings.UserSettings.AzIdCallbackPath;
            options.SignedOutCallbackPath = appSettings.UserSettings.AzIdSignOutCallbackPath;
        });
    services.AddAuthorization();
```

Then in the `Configure` method, I've added:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

When I try to access a controller action protected by the `[Authorize]` attribute, it correctly redirects me to the microsoft login page, however after I log in when the app then tries to redirect to my callback path (`/signin-oidc`) the connection gets reset and I get this browser error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a good example online on how to properly configure this?

Comment: I was playing with this example from Microsoft that works. I hope it will help you also: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C

Comment: in AD, the "Reply url" must be filled with actual URL that exists in your web app. See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this error was happening because I had set the cookie's `SameSite` attribute to `None` with this code (I need it to be `None` for some cross-domain calls that are done to the server):

```
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    //In-memory cookie store, so sessions are forcibly killed when the webapp restarts
    //This ensures that the user's Claims are up to date - remember to restart the service when Azure AD security group memberships are changed!
    options.SessionStore = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<MemoryCacheTicketStore>();

    //We want to disable the same-site policy, otherwise cross-domain API calls from JS won't work
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
});
```

apparently this by itself causes the error. To fix it, I had to also add the following code:

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility(s => false);
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });
```

this seems to have fixed the problem.